# Hierarchical labels or dense nodes?

Tags: neo4j, label, nodes

(I am new to Neo4J and very excited about it)

Here is my conceptual question:
Suppose we want to represent life on earth (based on a biological taxonomy hierarchy).

However, suppose at the leaves of the taxonomy tree we want to actually identify individual organisms. For example, at the mammalia branch, the homo-sapient sub-branch we want to identify each and every one of 7 billion humans and do the same for some other branches (give an ID to every living known great Ape left in the wild and so on)

Is this type of organization done with dense nodes (in the billions) ? or is it done with extensive use of labels (do labels support nesting)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view it's better to use multiple nodes instead of multiple labels.

But it depends on the use case and what you want to do with it.

Neo4j doesn't support nested labels or some labels hierarchy.

Here are some resources which could be interesting for you

- [Graph Databases in Life Sciences: Bringing Biology Back to Its Nature](https://vimeo.com/77450061)
- [Open Tree of Life and Neo4j](https://vimeo.com/67870035)